# Only keep paired rows in dataframe

Tags: r

From my data frame I want to keep only rows that contain a paired samples as indicated by `P1` and `PN1`, `P2` and `PN2` etc. The pairs always occur as P and PN following identical numbers. In my examples P3 and P4 does not have paired samples.

```
      value Sample
P1    0.0000     P1
PN1   0.0000    PN1
P2    0.0000     P2
PN2   0.0000    PN2
P3    0.0000     P3
P4  384.9141     P4
```

out

```
      value Sample
P1    0.0000     P1
PN1   0.0000    PN1
P2    0.0000     P2
PN2   0.0000    PN2
```

Comment: I'm very much interested to see answer for this, May be `grep`.

Comment: For my understand.. You want to keep rows where P(i) and PN(i) have the same value? Do the value itself matter?

Comment: @ika8 that is correct. the values does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

I assume that paired entries always have `Sample` names like (`P1`, `PN1`), (`P2`, `PN2`), and so on.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(id = sub("N", "", Sample)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    filter(n == 2) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-id, -n)
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  value Sample
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1    0. P1
#2    0. PN1
#3    0. P2
#4    0. PN2
```

Explanation: Create new column `id` from `Sample` where we have substituted `PN1` with `P1` and so on; group by `id`, count the number of rows per group, and only keep those entries with `2` rows per group.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "      value Sample
P1    0.0000     P1
PN1   0.0000    PN1
P2    0.0000     P2
PN2   0.0000    PN2
P3    0.0000     P3
P4  384.9141     P4", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast base R solution

```
df[(pmax(duplicated(gsub(".*(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$Sample)), duplicated(gsub(".*(\\d+)$", "\\1", df$Sample), fromLast=TRUE))==1), ]

  # value Sample
# 1     0     P1
# 2     0    PN1
# 3     0     P2
# 4     0    PN2
```

Data

```
structure(list(value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 384.9141), Sample = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "PN1", 
"PN2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "Sample"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question as stated, but it seems like your data may be better stored in "wide" format. After converting to a wide df, you can jus use `complete.cases` to remove rows where both cases `P` and `PN` are not present.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(N = ifelse(grepl('N', Sample), 'PN', 'P'),
         Sample = gsub('P|PN', '', Sample)) %>% 
  spread(N, value) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))

#   Sample P PN
# 1      1 0  0
# 2      2 0  0
```